# How can I simplify hierarchical class structure resulting in chained method calls?

Tags: design-patterns, oop, hierarchical-data

I have the following hierarchy of classes in a problem that I am working on.

```
DiscountEvent
  DiscountGroup
    ProductFamily
      Product
```

where each class contains a collection of next one (e.g. DiscountEvent contains a collection of DiscountGroups, etc)

This kind of a somewhat deep hierarchy results in many chained calls from the higher modules. 
For example, while reading product data from the database into this class hierarchy I have chains of calls and similar `AddProduct` methods.

```
class DiscountEvent{
  Dictionary<int, DiscountGroup> DiscountGroups;
  public void AddProduct(ProductInfo info){
    DiscountGroups[info.groupId].AddProduct(info);
  }
  ...
}
class DiscountGroup{
  Dictionary<int, productFamily> productFamilies;
  public void AddProduct(ProductInfo info){
    productFamilies[info.familyId].AddProduct(info);
  }
  ...
}
...
```

Similar add methods all the way to the leaf class. Can you think of any way to simplify this kind of a hierarchical class structure?

Comment: That's not a class heirarchy, because they do not inherit from each other. It's just a somewhat complex data structure.

Comment: @sje397: Well, there are many kinds of hierarchies. :-) You have specialisation hierarchies (the ones you're referring to) but mereological hierarchies too (the ones the question is referring to). So I see no problem there.

Comment: @CesarGon: 'class heirarchy' in OOP terminology refers to inheritance relationships between classes. If you're going to use terms from mereology, then we're not even talking about the same kind of 'class'.

Comment: @sje397: I am sorry to disagree; I have been writing professionally about software engineering for 15 years and using "hierarchy" to refer to mereological hierarchies as well. Most of my colleagues agree. Maybe we need to acknowledge that different sub-communities in software make different uses of the word; let's not be dogmatic.

Comment: @CesarGon: Fair enough point about dogma - a pet hate of mine too. But this usage is confusing. Yes, 'heirarchy' can refer to a lot of things, but I'm specifically referring to the use of the term 'class heirarchy' in the question. In my many years of reading about & studying software engineering I've never seen the above kind of data structure referred to as a 'class heirarchy' and in my understanding that is just plain incorrect.

Comment: ...(about as incorrect as my spelling :)...

Comment: i specifically avoided using "class hierarchy" to avoid confusion with inheritance.  turns out "hierarchical class structure" is confusing too. how do i change the wording to get some answers?

Comment: @sje397: Fair enough then. :-)

Comment: @derdo: You can edit your own question and rephrase it if you want. I suggest "class structure" if you want to avoid confusion as sje397 pointed out.

Comment: @dredo: "...from the database into this class hierarchy..." is the bit I was taking about.

Answer (score 0):

Most modern [ORM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) could solve this problem for you.

You can't actually simplify your "hierarchy" because it based on real-life abstractions, but you can simplify your life eliminating manual child's populations.

In this case you still need all child collections (because this is part of your domain logic or data access layer), but all this complexity (with populating them) would hide by ORB implementation.

Answer (score 0):

One idea would be to use a form of the [Serializer Pattern](http://cartan.cas.suffolk.edu/oopdocbook/html/serializer.html)...because you are 'deserializing' from a database.

That is, you might have a `DiscountEventReader` class into which you pass the database connection - and it might call other reader classes to create the contained object instances.

This has the advantage that, for example, a ProductFamilyReader could read (and potentially cache) multiple database rows, adding multiple `Product` instances to the parent container without traversing the entire hierarchy of 'addProduct' calls for each new object.